# Is there a common practice for handling several methods with the same logic?

Tags: c#, methods

I have a simple menu with buttons in it. Each button opens another form.

```
public void apartmentDetailsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var form = new ApartmentDetails.View())
    {
        form.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
public void remindersButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var form = new Reminders.View())
    {
        form.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
public void paymentsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var form = new Payments.View())
    {
        form.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
public void documentsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var form = new Documents.View())
    {
        form.ShowDialog(view);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the event handlers do pretty much the same thing, except the namespace which contains the required form. Now, what if I have much more buttons? Should I really copy-paste this method each and every time?

Is there possibility to use one eventhandler for all buttons or generalize existed handlers?

Comment: You can have one event method handle more than one button.  Just change name of method where the event is registered using '+='.

Comment: Thanks. How could I know which namespace to refer to?

Comment: @Sipo: the sender parameter is a reference to the button that was clicked - so you could check that to see which namespace is required.

Comment: @PaulF - by using the `Tag` or something like that?

Comment: If you are using a Windows Form Project the code normally is in the designer.cs file.  So you can move the code from the designer into your form constructor or load method.  Then change naming of calling method to be the same for all the buttons.

Comment: See KMoussa's comments to the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all types implements or derives from a common type you can declare a  method like this:

```
public void DisplayForm(CommonType f)
{
    using(var form = f.View())
    {
        form.ShowDialog(view);
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
DisplayForm(new Documents());
```

`CommonType` should be the one that contains `View` method.

In order to reduce the amount of event handlers you can declare one event handler and check the type of `sender`:

```
public void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is ApartmentDetails)
    {
        DisplayForm(new ApartmentDetails());
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Even with generic approach OP need to create own event handler for every button

Comment: Why does it need to be a generic method rather than `public void DisplayForm(ICommonInterface f)` ?

Comment: @KMoussa you are right, that would work as well. I guess this scenario seemed a perfect place to use generics for me at the first glance :)

Comment: @SelmanGenç, Thanks! So I would still need to write one event handler per button?

Comment: @Sipo yes, this would make your code shorter but you need a different event handler for each button. you can ofcourse use the same handler for all of them and check the type of sender parameter, and then create appropriate form based on that.

Comment: OP don't need even common interface, since object he created are forms which all derived from `Form`

Comment: @Sipo maybe u can use a mix of what you proposed above (using `Tag`) and what @SelmanGenç mentioned here. You can set all tags in code (`paymentsButton.Tag = new Payments.View()` etc) and then have a single handler that does `((sender as Button).Tag as Form).ShowDialog()` .. or `as ICommonInterface` depending on whether all the tags will be forms ... u also need null checks etc but that's the basic idea

Comment: I have updated the answer based on ur suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Because your eventhandlers dealing with different types you cannot create one eventhandler for all buttons.

One of workarounds can be using of `Activator.CreateInstance`, but only in case when all forms can be created with constructor of same signature

```
public void OnClick(Type viewType, Form parent)
{
    using (var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType))
    {
        form.ShowDialog(parent);
    } 
}
```

Then in constructor use  it for all buttons

```
apartmentDetailsButton.Click += (sender, args) => OnClick(typeof(ApartmentDetails.View), this);
remindersButton.Click += (sender, args) => OnClick(typeof(Reminders.View), this);    
paymentsButton.Click += (sender, args) => OnClick(typeof(Payments.View), this);
```

You can get rid from lambdas by saving type of displayed form in the `button.Tag`

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var viewType = (Type)button.Tag;

    using (var form = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(viewType))
    {
        form.ShowDialog(this);
    } 
}
```

Then "subscribe" to events

```
apartmentDetailsButton.Tag = typeof(ApartmentDetails.View);
apartmentDetailsButton.Click += OnButtonClick;

apartmentDetailsButton.Tag = typeof(Reminders.View);
remindersButton.Click += OnButtonClick;
```